# Docker containers runs great locally. Now I need it on schedule in cloud

Tags: azure, docker

I've containerized a logic that I have to run on a schedule. If I do my docker run locally (whatever my image is local or it is using the one from the hub) everything works great.

Now I need though to run that "docker run" on a scheduled base, on the cloud.

Azure would be preferred, but honestly, I'm looking for the easier and cheapest way to achieve this goal.

Moreover, my schedule can change, so maybe today that job runs once a day, in the future that can change.

What do you suggest?

Comment: What does it do, the logic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an [Azure Logic app](https://azure.microsoft.com/de-de/services/logic-apps/) to [trigger the start of a Azure Container Instance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/connectors/connectors-create-api-container-instances). As you have a "run-once" (every N minute/hour/..) container, the restart-policy should be set to "Never", so that the container only executes and then stops after the scheduling.

The Logic app needs to have the permissions to start the Container, so add a role assignment on the ACI to the managed identity of the logic App.

Screenshot shows the workflow with a Recurrence trigger, that starts an existing container every minute.

Should be quite cheap and utilizes only Azure services, without any custom infrastructure

[image]

Comment: this sounds promising @burna ! I pushed my container to ACI, but right away I'm having the problem that the instance fails with only this error from azure: `standard_init_linux.go:178: exec user process caused "exec format error"` With so little info I don't even know how to start troubleshooting

Comment: Are you building your container on an ARM machine?

Comment: Yep @CSharpRocks Mac M1

Comment: like @CSharpRocks mentioned, looks like the application is built for another platform. You can look at `docker buildx` to build multi-platform images: https://docs.docker.com/buildx/working-with-buildx/#build-multi-platform-images

Comment: @burna I thought the same, but if that's the reason, why I can run it from my windows WSL machine? What's architecture is ACI expecting?

Comment: You could try to `docker inspect mytag:1` the image on your WSL and on your Mac - there should be a property "Architecture" that tells the platform

Comment: ACI should expect amd64 per default, didn't see support for amd64

Comment: @burna did you mean `didn't see support for *arm64*`. I looked for a list of supported platforms, find none

Comment: Btw, following this I solved it: https://betterprogramming.pub/how-to-actually-deploy-docker-images-built-on-a-m1-macs-with-apple-silicon-a35e39318e97

Comment: Yes, of course `arm64`. So, did it work for you now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/239259/discussion-between-ff8mania-and-burna).

Answer (score 1):

Professionally I used 4 ways to run cron jobs/ scheduled builds. I give a quick summary of all with it pros/cons.

## GitLab scheduled builds (free)

My personal preference would be to setup a [scheduled pipeline](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/pipelines/schedules.html) in GitLab. Simply add the script to a `.gitlab-ci.yml`, configure the scheduled build and you are done. This is the lightweight option and works in most cases, if the execution time is not too long. I used this approach for scraping simple pages.

## Jenkins scheduled builds (not-free)

I used the same approach as GitLab with Jenkins. But Jenkins comes with more overhead and you have to configure the entire Jenkins on multiple machines.

## Kubernetes CronJob (expensive)

My third approach would be using a [kubernetes cronjob](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/cron-jobs/). However, I would only use this if I consume a lot of memory/ram, or have a long execution time. I used this approach for dumping really large data sets.

## Run a cron job from a container (expensive)

My last option would be to deploy a docker container on either a VM or a Kubernetes cluster and configure a cron job from within that docker container. You can even use `docker-in-docker` for that. This gives maximum flexibility, but comes with some challenges. Personally I like the separation of concerns when it comes to down-times etc. That's why never run a cron job as main process.